# How to not export all functions/methods from a package in perl?

Tags: perl, object

I am playing around with a existing perl module lets call it Obj.
I have added some new features (subroutines / methods) to Obj but store them in another .pm call it Foo. However I dont want Obj to inherit every sub from Foo.

Now I have been reading perl documentation for a few hours and am confused.
https://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter#Selecting-What-to-Export
Just says 'Do not export method names!'

Here is some example code, I'd like to not see sub _not_exported from Obj.pm:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

package Foo;# Foo is a new PM file used to extend Obj with collections of subroutine's.
# I want to use hello() from Obj
    #use Exporter 'import';
    use Exporter qw(import);
    our @EXPORT_OK = qw/hello/;

    sub hello {
            my $self = shift;
            $self->{test} = 'Hello world';
    }
    # I'd rather not pollute Obj with this sub
    # or perfreably all subs the begin with a underscore
    # How do I exclude this sub?
    sub _not_exported { 
        my $self = shift;
        return 'Exported';
    }


    #main old code object module 
package Obj; # large old PM file I dont want to change this file much
    # pull in the new module
    use base 'Foo'; 
    # use base seems better than this:
    #import Foo;
    #our @ISA = qw(Foo);
    sub new {
        
            my $self = {};
            bless $self, 'Obj';
            return $self;
    }
    eval { $this = $form->_not_exported() } ; #Should return nothing
    
    sub catch_hash {
        my ($self,$arg) = @_; 
        $arg |= '';
        $self->{test} = 'catch';
    }

    
#Perl script, creates an object using Obj;
package main;
    #use Obj;
    import Obj;

    my $form = Obj->new();
    $form->catch_hash();
    print "Toss? '$form->{test}' \n";
    $form->hello();
    print "\nHello? '$form->{test}'\n";
    my $this = "";
    eval { $this = $form->_not_exported() } ; #Should return nothing
    print "$this\ndone\n";

    
1;
```

I am open to other options like Moo / Moose but dont want to change the old code much.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use [namespace::clean](https://metacpan.org/pod/namespace::clean). (Note that you'd have to use `private($form)` rather than `$form->private()`.)

Comment: I've edited your question to remove the link to a pirate copy of a book.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Note: I'm am a former maintainer of Exporter]

I believe you've confused exporting with inheritance. That's easy to do, Perl doesn't draw a line between "function" and "method", they're just `sub`.

***tl;dr*** You don't need to export, that's just how inheritance works, there is a work around.

---

Exporting lets you call a function from outside of a package without fully qualifying it. It would let you call `Foo::hello` as just `hello`. Exporting lets Perl know that `hello` really means `hello` in package `Foo`.

But these are method calls, and you call them on a class or object. `my $foo = Foo->new; $foo->hello`. No exporting required. `Foo->new` calls `new` in `Foo` and returns a `Foo` object. `$foo->hello` knows to look for the method `foo` in the ancestry of `$foo`'s class. You don't need to use exporter in a class, that's what "Do not export method names" means.

Exporting is a deliberate act which copies symbols around. Inheritance is all or nothing. If you inherit from a class you get all its methods (subs). This is a consequence of inheritance, and there are many other alternatives to inheritance such as [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

In other OO languages you could declare the method `private` and it would not be inherited. Perl doesn't have that. Normally you just live with this by convention as you have, put an underscore in front of the method name, don't document it, and if somebody uses it that's their problem. And that's usually fine.

But you can make truly private methods with [anonymous subs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Anonymous-Subroutines) and [lexical variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29).

```
package Foo;

# Define `new` in Foo. Obj will inherit it.
# Do not hard code the class.
# `new` receives the class new was called on.
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {}, $class;
}

sub hello {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->{test} = 'Hello world';
}

# This is a reference to an anonymous function in a lexical variable.
# It can only be seen by the code after this line in this file.
my $private_method = sub { 
    my $self = shift;
    return "private method called by $self with args: @_\n";
};

sub public_method {
    my $self = shift;

    # $private_method can be seen here.
    # A subroutine reference can be called like a method.
    print $self->$private_method("basset hounds got long ears");
}
```

And in Obj.pm

```
package Obj;

# parent is a lightweight replacement for base.
use parent 'Foo';
```

Obj inherits `new` and `hello` and `public_method` from `Foo`, but it cannot see $private_method. It can only be seen inside Foo.pm.

```
my $obj = Obj->new;

# private method called by Obj=HASH(0x7fcfdb8126d8) with args: basset hounds got long ears
$obj->public_method;
```

Because `public_method` is defined where it can see `$private_method`, `$obj->public_method` will work despite being called on an instance of Obj and not Foo.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation, I think I am still confused but this gets me on the right track. Ill keep using the underscore and not worry about it

Comment: @turtle I added a `new` method in `Foo` to complete the example. Note how I've written it so it can be inherited.

Comment: @zdim Perl is so big there's always something else to learn!